# Use cshtml in image tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

I have an svg code inside a cshtml file.  Was wondering if there was a way to add that code/svg into an image tag (so I can take advantage of the image tag's alt tag for accessibility purposes)

circle.cshtml

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>
```

myview.cshtml

```
<img src="@Html.Partial(~/circle.cshtml)" alt="red circle />
```

The above code doesn't work.

Comment: You can encode an svg as a data uri. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs. So you'd need to work out how to read from a `IHtmlContent` and encode the result...

Answer (score 0):

You should create an action in controller and returns this partial view result and use the image src attribute value in view.

in controller:

```
public ActionResult Circle()
{
    return PartialView("_circle");
}
```

in razor:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Circle")" />
```